# Python programming for calculation of sales summery

Tags: python

```
DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE1=0.02
DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE2=0.05
DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE3=0.10



def main():
   res='y'
     while res=='y':
    print('year  :  2017')
    month=input('Please enter the month: ')
    day=int(input('please enter the day: '))
    Fruit=input('Please enter the Fruit: ')
    grade=input('please enter grade:')

    Price=float(input('please enter the price($/Kg): '))
    kilos=float(input('No of kilograms: '))
    print('date:',day,month ,'2017')


    Total=Price * kilos
    tax= 0.10 * Total

    print('items:','grade','quantity:', 'price:', 'Total :','discount',  'GST in price:',sep=' ')
    print(Fruit, 'grade',grade ,  'kg',kilos, '$',Price,  '$'       ,Total,    '$',Discount,'$' ,format(tax,',.2f'),sep=' ')
    res=input('do you want to check another number?[y/n]:')

def Discount(Price,grade):
if grade==1:
    return
    Discount=Price*DISCOUNT_PERCENTAGE1
else:
     Discount=0
main()
```

---

in the last section of the code i have an error code for Discount function
in output like this 'function Discount at 0x100662e18 '

output :

```
year  :  2017
Please enter the month: sep
please enter the day: 1
Please enter the Fruit: ap
please enter grade:1
please enter the price($/Kg): 2
No of kilograms: 2
date: 1 sep 2017
items: grade quantity: price: Total : discount GST in price:
ap grade 1 kg 2.0 $ 2.0 $ 4.0 $ <function Discount at 0x100662e18> $ 0.40
do you want to check another number?[y/n]:
```

any help regarding that error code ?
i need to program like if grade=1 or 2 or 3 the discount will vary for grade to grade and in the total price too 
i tried in different ways but no luck !'

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What error code?

Comment: error is <function Discount at 0x100662e18>

Comment: Why do you duplicate the condition in `while res=='y' or res=='y':`? You also set `res='y'` in the previous line, so you'd really be better off using `while True` and a break/return.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're observing is that you're printing `Discount`, which is a function, so your output is its representation. Instead, call the function:

```
print(Fruit, 'grade', grade, 'kg', kilos, '$', Price, '$', Total, '$', Discount(Price, grade), '$', format(tax, ',.2f'), sep=' ')
```

Notice that I've replaced `Discount` with `Discount(Price, grade)`. You'll still need to work on your `Discount` function to get your script to run, though.

Comment: I called the function ,now it is printing <None> ,I'm working on Discount function now,thanks.

Comment: @zealmonkey: Sure thing, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If an answer helps you, you can choose to give it an upvote, and if you deem it correct, you can "accept" it as the answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: yeah sure thing tanks again

Comment: Do you know how to call a function as float or integer that we used to do math like 
   output is like " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'function' "

Comment: @zealmonkey: If you need assistance further than this question addresses, you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Best of luck.